# ANTLR treats part of string as a keyword

Tags: java, antlr

I'm currently learning ANTLR for myself. First of I decided to write the simplest grammar. There is plain text file with directives:

```
pid = something.pid
log = something.log
```

The grammar I wrote is:

```
grammar TestGrammar;

options {
  language = Java;
}

@header {
  package test.antlr;
}

@lexer::header {
  package test.antlr;
}

program
  : directive+
  ;

directive
  : pid
  | log
  ;

pid
  : PID EQ (WORD|POINT)+
  ;

log
  : LOG EQ (WORD|POINT)+
  ;

WS: ( ' '
    | '\t'
    | '\r'
    | '\n'
    ) {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;

PID
  : 'pid'
  ;

LOG
  : 'log'
  ;

EQ
  : '='
  ;

POINT
  : '.'
  ;

WORD
  : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_')+
  ;
```

I feel I made a mistake somewhere and ANTLR proves that throwing `MismatchedTokenException`. It treats something.**pid** as a `directive` and throws an exception.

However I don't understand what am I doing wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lexer is a very simple object: without interference from the parser, it tokenizes the input source. So, the input:

```
pid = something.pid
```

is **not** tokenized as:

```
PID EQ WORD POINT WORD
```

but as:

```
PID EQ WORD POINT PID
```

That's why your rule:

```
pid
  : PID EQ (WORD|POINT)+
  ;
```

matches `"pid = something."` and leaves the second `"pid"` in the token-stream, expecting an `EQ` atfer it (hence the exception).

A possible fix would be to do something like this:

```
pid
  : PID EQ (word|POINT)+
  ;

log
  : LOG EQ (word|POINT)+
  ;

word
  : WORD
  | PID
  | LOG 
  ;
```

Or by doing something like:

```
pid
  : PID EQ FULL_WORD
  ;

log
  : LOG EQ FULL_WORD
  ;

// ...

FULL_WORD
  : WORD (POINT WORD)*
  ;

// ...
```